# Quaternion Lerp not giving good results with LookRotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to flip my first person character smoothly while being able to rotate the player in y-axis using mouse look. The problem is the lerp does not end with an exact result. I want the ending rotation result to be exact such that (transform.up == TargetUpDirection())

```
void FixOrientation() {
    if(transform.up != TargetUpDirection()) //Vector3(0, -1, 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = 
            Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,
                            Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward,
                            TargetUpDirection(), 0.1f);
    }
}
```

if I use mouse look while it flips, transform.up.y always result with less than 1 like for example 0.99881231 and I need to keep using mouse look until it corrects itself and I don't like it.

The cause is probably that when I use mouse look, the character forward gets modified which is causing this but I don't know how to implement a solution because quaternions confuses me.

Comment: `Quaternion.Lerp` need 3 arguments.

Comment: sorry i edited it to add the 3rd one

Comment: I would try slerp instead of lerp, but I think the actual problem is probably gimbal lock in your mouselook function.

Comment: Definitely use `Slerp` but gimbal lock is not the issue since he is using Quaternions.

Comment: I think you are missing a `)` after `TargetUpDirection()`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because as written, `Lerp` is always rotating you 10% of the way remaining. This means that as you approach the target rotation, the amount by which you are rotated will decrease. Eventually, it will decrease to a point where rounding errors make you rotate by 0 degrees, before you actually arrive at the destination.

In most cases, you do not want to call `Lerp` with a constant value for `t`.

Here is an alternative. First, pick a maximum rotational speed:

```
float smooth = 5f;
```

Then, use `Quaternion.RotateTowards`:

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, TargetUpDirection());
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation , smooth * Time.deltaTime);
```

This answer was based off [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-quaternion-smooth-rotation.325444/#post-2111443) on the Unity forums.

Comment: For my solution. I just locked my mouse look when the transform is being oriented and just unlock it when the up is now aligned. not the best solution but it can work